# Über die Silbenmessung eines Gedichtes: Vokale

Tags: poetry

Wie zählt man die Silben eines Gedichtes? Die Frage bezieht sich besonders auf die Vokalbindungen. Gibt es das im Deutschen?

Zum Beispiel, nehmen wir – ganz zufällig und sinnlos – zwei Wörter, von denen eines mit Vokal endet und das Andere mit dem gleichen Vokal anfängt:

> (…) schöne Erinnerungen (…)

Wie viele Silben hat dieses Paar? Sechs oder sieben?

Ändern wir jetzt den Vokal eines Wortes:

> (…) schlechte Oper (…)

Wie viele Silben hat dieses Paar? Drei oder vier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im Deutschen werden Vokale, die an Wortgrenzen aufeinandertreffen, niemals miteinander verschmolzen. Eine Ursache dafür ist vermutlich, daß der Fall strenggenommen gar nicht auftritt, weil immer ein glottaler Plosiv die Vokale trennt (vgl. [A few questions about glottal stops in Standard German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7226)). Dementsprechend haben deine Beispiele sieben bzw. vier Silben.

Wenn Vokale ausgelassen werden und sich dadurch die Silbenzahl ändert, wird das normalerweise in der Schreibung entsprechend wiedergegeben: *Erinnrung*, *ich seh’s*, *Bemühn*.

Comment: Der glottal stop tritt entsprechend auch innerhalb eines Wortes auf (z.B. bei *beehre mich bald wieder* in *be-ehre*; dagegen natürlich nicht zwischen den nur geschrieben zwei *e*'s in *Erdbeere*)

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Ja, das ist in meiner Antwort auf die verlinkte Frage näher beschrieben.